# How do I get the values of each key in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Initially, I got just the values of each key, but now I realized that I will be needing the keys themselves and then get the values of those keys. I commented out what I did before.

[image: Database Structure]

```
    // READ LIST OF STORIES (myFirebase.js)
  getListOfStories(location, callWhenFinished) {
      let ref = firebase.database().ref(location)
      ref
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
          let listOfStoryKeys = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var key = childSnapshot.key
              listOfStoryKeys.push(key);
          })
          for (var storyKey in listOfStoryKeys) {
              // printing each story key
              console.log(listOfStoryKeys[storyKey])
          }
          callWhenFinished(listOfStoryKeys);
          // var listOfStories = snapshot.val() || []  // all stories or none at all
          // callWhenFinished(Object.values(listOfStories));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Couldn't get list of objects: " + error);
          callWhenFinished([])
      });
  }

 // OTHERPAGE.js Show stories and their values from the DB and into the console 
  displayStoriesOnPage = (stories) => {
    if (stories.length === 0) {
      console.log("Error: Did not get list of stories!");
      return;
    }
    // Initially got all the values of each story;
    // Now need to get values of each story using their keys
    /*
    console.log(stories);
    for (var iStory in stories) {
      const story = stories[iStory]
      console.log("Story: " + story);
      for (var iAttr in story) {
        const attr = story[iAttr];
        console.log("\t " + iAttr + ": " + attr);
      }
    }
    */
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        allStories: stories,
      };
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain? What do you have about the story and what do you want to get?

Comment: @ Dharmaraj I would like to get the values (actual data) using each key. For example, the key "-MftXA1QzVOMnf4qbako" should give me all of its data or children (imgID, language, location, status, title, userID). I initially just got each set of data easily, but I am now struggling to get a set of data through its unique key

Comment: When you are fetching the data, you are not storing anything except the keys. Now you can make another request to Firebase to get data of key by setting ref to `.ref("stories/"+theKey)` but that's redundant. Follow the detailed answer by @Frank.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/ova4y0/how_do_i_get_the_values_of_each_key/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both the keys and the values of the stories, one way to do that is to pass two parameters to your `callWhenFinished` callback:

```
  getListOfStories(location, callWhenFinished) {
      let ref = firebase.database().ref(location)
      ref
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
          let listOfStoryKeys = [],
              listOfStoryValues = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              listOfStoryKeys.push(childSnapshot.key);
              listOfStoryValues.push(childSnapshot.val());
          })
          callWhenFinished(listOfStoryKeys, listOfStoryValues);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Couldn't get list of objects: " + error);
          callWhenFinished([], [])
      });
  }
```

---

You can also put the keys and values in a single array, giving the key a name that you're not using for any of your other properties (like `$key`). That'd look something like:

```
  getListOfStories(location, callWhenFinished) {
      let ref = firebase.database().ref(location)
      ref
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
          let listOfStories = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              let story = childSnapshot.val();
              story["$id"] = childSnapshot.key;
              listOfStories.push(story);
          })
          callWhenFinished(listOfStories);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Couldn't get list of objects: " + error);
          callWhenFinished([])
      });
  }
```

---

No matter which option you use, you can then iterate over the story values/keys in the callback implementation, and access both the key and the property values.